# inputAccessoryView does not be removed

Tags: ios, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

first:

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = bar;
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

later:

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = nil;
[textView reloadInputViews];
[textView resignFirstResponder];
[self.view addSubView:bar];
```

bar is the inputAccessoryView. It's not be added to self.view. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

please add inputAccessoryView view after delay like

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = nil;
[textView resignFirstResponder];
[self.view performSelector:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:bar afterDelay:1];
```